# Manipulate and remove a DOM element from parsed HTML 

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm new to both HTML & PHP. I'm attempting to remove multiple DOM elements from a parsed HTML string.

For example:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>I'd like to find and remove this text</td>
        <td>&amp; possibly this too</td>
        <td>can you help?</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please include more information in your question like where the html is coming from, is it a string, what are you doing with it. etc.

Comment: It's just an example, I am still learning the language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very simply if I were to remove lots of things from a string in PHP I would create an array of the parts to remove, loop through them and remove them one at a time from the big string.

Like

```
$html = "Loads of html blah blah blah blah......";

$array = array(
        "Remove me",
        "and me",
        "remove me too"
        );

foreach($array as $string){
    str_replace($string, '', $html);
}
```

For more information on str_replace see http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: This solution is extremely inflexible, requires you to know all of the strings to remove ahead of time, and may remove parts of the HTML that aren't text nodes.

Comment: That is true but it's not really intended as a copy and paste solution. The array of things to remove are just an example of how to structure it, you could load these from anywhere. But yes this is not a perfect way to implement but the question was how to remove parts of a string with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`DOMDocument` is much better for dealing with DOM manipulation (`SimpleXML` is good for just parsing):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//text()');
foreach ($textNodes as $node) {
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: If the rest of the code is based on the simple html dom is it possible to use the DOMdocument code inside of it?

Comment: @user1685565 definitely; there are even functions to convert `SimpleXML` objects to `DOMDocument` and back.